# Tkinter Label Text Not Appearing

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I use this code (from https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_labels.php) but no text appears in the label.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
w = tk.Label(root, text="Hello Tkinter!")
w.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I suspect that any problem may involve the `mainloop` function.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, and I see absolutely nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I tested it again and it works. Weird.